# Is YAML inheritance (merege key) an official feature?

Tags: yaml

[Wikipedia describes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Advanced_components)
 a simple inheritance feature for map nodes in YAML (aka merge key):

```
- step:  &id001
    instrument: Lasik 2000
    spotSize: 1mm
- step:
    <<: *id001
    spotSize: 2mm    # redefines just this key, refers rest from &id001
```

I was not able to find a description of this feature in the [official specifications](http://yaml.org/). Is it an undocumented feature, a common extension to the specification, or something else? Does any spec-compliant YAML parser implement this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature is semi-official, it is a [merge key](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html). It is [defined as optional extension for YAML 1.1 and has not been updated for YAML 1.2](https://web.archive.org/web/20181004131257/https://sourceforge.net/p/yaml/mailman/message/34754791/) and most people in the YAML community agree that it's deprecated and should not be used.

So as both an optional extension and a deprecated feature, you cannot depend on it and should consult the documentation of the YAML implementation you're using.

> Does any spec-compliant YAML parser implements this feature?

- [SnakeYaml](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-merge)
- [YamlDotNet](http://aaubry.net/pages/yamldotnet.html)
- [PyYAML](https://pyyaml.org/)
- [ruamel](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml)
- Possibly others I do not know about.